# Word Cities/Towns/Countries database for MongoDB (or in JSON)?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mongodb, lithium

I'm developing a application using MongoDB. One of the standard functionality I want to provide on the front-end is the 'auto-suggest' feature as one types in the first few letters of a city (example: If I start typing 'Mu...', it should suggest to the user 'Mumbai/India'.

I have seen a few threads here and also few sites on google which are databases of cites, essentially RDBMS based.

Anyone here used or put-together a document database for such information of cities/countries? If so, I would love to hear about the source of the data and the steps they followed to import it in Lithium/Backbone/MongoDB application including any relevant learnings.

EDIT:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete
Has anyone used Facebook or Google Places API for looking up cities/countries in a live/production environment? Did it meet your needs in-terms of response speed and stability etc?

Comment: It should'nt be a problem to write a PHP Script that transfers a RDMBMS  based Database to Mongo

Comment: True, won't be very difficult to import it in Mongo. Although I'm now also considering using Google Places API and the facebook API (listed below)

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). You have to write your own script to parse the data and insert into MongoDB. Download GeoNames dump file [here](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/).

Answer (score 7):

Please find the below JSON countries list :

```
[{"country_code":"AD","country_name":"Andorra"}, {"country_code":"AE","country_name":"United Arab Emirates"}, {"country_code":"AF","country_name":"Afghanistan"}, {"country_code":"AG","country_name":"Antigua and Barbuda"}, {"country_code":"AI","country_name":"Anguilla"}, {"country_code":"AL","country_name":"Albania"}, {"country_code":"AM","country_name":"Armenia"}, {"country_code":"AO","country_name":"Angola"}, {"country_code":"AQ","country_name":"Antarctica"}, {"country_code":"AR","country_name":"Argentina"}, {"country_code":"AS","country_name":"American Samoa"}, {"country_code":"AT","country_name":"Austria"}, {"country_code":"AU","country_name":"Australia"}, {"country_code":"AW","country_name":"Aruba"}, {"country_code":"AX","country_name":"\u00c5land"}, {"country_code":"AZ","country_name":"Azerbaijan"}, {"country_code":"BA","country_name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina"}, {"country_code":"BB","country_name":"Barbados"}, {"country_code":"BD","country_name":"Bangladesh"}, {"country_code":"BE","country_name":"Belgium"}, {"country_code":"BF","country_name":"Burkina Faso"}, {"country_code":"BG","country_name":"Bulgaria"}, {"country_code":"BH","country_name":"Bahrain"}, {"country_code":"BI","country_name":"Burundi"}, {"country_code":"BJ","country_name":"Benin"}, {"country_code":"BL","country_name":"Saint Barth\u00e9lemy"}, {"country_code":"BM","country_name":"Bermuda"}, {"country_code":"BN","country_name":"Brunei"}, {"country_code":"BO","country_name":"Bolivia"}, {"country_code":"BQ","country_name":"Bonaire"}, {"country_code":"BR","country_name":"Brazil"}, {"country_code":"BS","country_name":"Bahamas"}, {"country_code":"BT","country_name":"Bhutan"}, {"country_code":"BV","country_name":"Bouvet Island"}, {"country_code":"BW","country_name":"Botswana"}, {"country_code":"BY","country_name":"Belarus"}, {"country_code":"BZ","country_name":"Belize"}, {"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada"}, {"country_code":"CC","country_name":"Cocos [Keeling] Islands"}, {"country_code":"CD","country_name":"Democratic Republic of the Congo"}, {"country_code":"CF","country_name":"Central African Republic"}, {"country_code":"CG","country_name":"Republic of the Congo"}, {"country_code":"CH","country_name":"Switzerland"}, {"country_code":"CI","country_name":"Ivory Coast"}, {"country_code":"CK","country_name":"Cook Islands"}, {"country_code":"CL","country_name":"Chile"}, {"country_code":"CM","country_name":"Cameroon"}, {"country_code":"CN","country_name":"China"}, {"country_code":"CO","country_name":"Colombia"}, {"country_code":"CR","country_name":"Costa Rica"}, {"country_code":"CU","country_name":"Cuba"}, {"country_code":"CV","country_name":"Cape Verde"}, {"country_code":"CW","country_name":"Curacao"}, {"country_code":"CX","country_name":"Christmas Island"}, {"country_code":"CY","country_name":"Cyprus"}, {"country_code":"CZ","country_name":"Czech Republic"}, {"country_code":"DE","country_name":"Germany"}, {"country_code":"DJ","country_name":"Djibouti"}, {"country_code":"DK","country_name":"Denmark"}, {"country_code":"DM","country_name":"Dominica"}, {"country_code":"DO","country_name":"Dominican Republic"}, {"country_code":"DZ","country_name":"Algeria"}, {"country_code":"EC","country_name":"Ecuador"}, {"country_code":"EE","country_name":"Estonia"}, {"country_code":"EG","country_name":"Egypt"}, {"country_code":"EH","country_name":"Western Sahara"}, {"country_code":"ER","country_name":"Eritrea"}, {"country_code":"ES","country_name":"Spain"}, {"country_code":"ET","country_name":"Ethiopia"}, {"country_code":"FI","country_name":"Finland"}, {"country_code":"FJ","country_name":"Fiji"}, {"country_code":"FK","country_name":"Falkland Islands"}, {"country_code":"FM","country_name":"Micronesia"}, {"country_code":"FO","country_name":"Faroe Islands"}, {"country_code":"FR","country_name":"France"}, {"country_code":"GA","country_name":"Gabon"}, {"country_code":"GB","country_name":"United Kingdom"}, {"country_code":"GD","country_name":"Grenada"}, {"country_code":"GE","country_name":"Georgia"}, {"country_code":"GF","country_name":"French Guiana"}, {"country_code":"GG","country_name":"Guernsey"}, {"country_code":"GH","country_name":"Ghana"}, {"country_code":"GI","country_name":"Gibraltar"}, {"country_code":"GL","country_name":"Greenland"}, {"country_code":"GM","country_name":"Gambia"}, {"country_code":"GN","country_name":"Guinea"}, {"country_code":"GP","country_name":"Guadeloupe"}, {"country_code":"GQ","country_name":"Equatorial Guinea"}, {"country_code":"GR","country_name":"Greece"}, {"country_code":"GS","country_name":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"}, {"country_code":"GT","country_name":"Guatemala"}, {"country_code":"GU","country_name":"Guam"}, {"country_code":"GW","country_name":"Guinea-Bissau"}, {"country_code":"GY","country_name":"Guyana"}, {"country_code":"HK","country_name":"Hong Kong"}, {"country_code":"HM","country_name":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands"}, {"country_code":"HN","country_name":"Honduras"}, {"country_code":"HR","country_name":"Croatia"}, {"country_code":"HT","country_name":"Haiti"}, {"country_code":"HU","country_name":"Hungary"}, {"country_code":"ID","country_name":"Indonesia"}, {"country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland"}, {"country_code":"IL","country_name":"Israel"}, {"country_code":"IM","country_name":"Isle of Man"}, {"country_code":"IN","country_name":"India"}, {"country_code":"IO","country_name":"British Indian Ocean Territory"}, {"country_code":"IQ","country_name":"Iraq"}, {"country_code":"IR","country_name":"Iran"}, {"country_code":"IS","country_name":"Iceland"}, {"country_code":"IT","country_name":"Italy"}, {"country_code":"JE","country_name":"Jersey"}, {"country_code":"JM","country_name":"Jamaica"}, {"country_code":"JO","country_name":"Jordan"}, {"country_code":"JP","country_name":"Japan"}, {"country_code":"KE","country_name":"Kenya"}, {"country_code":"KG","country_name":"Kyrgyzstan"}, {"country_code":"KH","country_name":"Cambodia"}, {"country_code":"KI","country_name":"Kiribati"}, {"country_code":"KM","country_name":"Comoros"}, {"country_code":"KN","country_name":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"}, {"country_code":"KP","country_name":"North Korea"}, {"country_code":"KR","country_name":"South Korea"}, {"country_code":"KW","country_name":"Kuwait"}, {"country_code":"KY","country_name":"Cayman Islands"}, {"country_code":"KZ","country_name":"Kazakhstan"}, {"country_code":"LA","country_name":"Laos"}, {"country_code":"LB","country_name":"Lebanon"}, {"country_code":"LC","country_name":"Saint Lucia"}, {"country_code":"LI","country_name":"Liechtenstein"}, {"country_code":"LK","country_name":"Sri Lanka"}, {"country_code":"LR","country_name":"Liberia"}, {"country_code":"LS","country_name":"Lesotho"}, {"country_code":"LT","country_name":"Lithuania"}, {"country_code":"LU","country_name":"Luxembourg"}, {"country_code":"LV","country_name":"Latvia"}, {"country_code":"LY","country_name":"Libya"}, {"country_code":"MA","country_name":"Morocco"}, {"country_code":"MC","country_name":"Monaco"}, {"country_code":"MD","country_name":"Moldova"}, {"country_code":"ME","country_name":"Montenegro"}, {"country_code":"MF","country_name":"Saint Martin"}, {"country_code":"MG","country_name":"Madagascar"}, {"country_code":"MH","country_name":"Marshall Islands"}, {"country_code":"MK","country_name":"Macedonia"}, {"country_code":"ML","country_name":"Mali"}, {"country_code":"MM","country_name":"Myanmar [Burma]"}, {"country_code":"MN","country_name":"Mongolia"}, {"country_code":"MO","country_name":"Macao"}, {"country_code":"MP","country_name":"Northern Mariana Islands"}, {"country_code":"MQ","country_name":"Martinique"}, {"country_code":"MR","country_name":"Mauritania"}, {"country_code":"MS","country_name":"Montserrat"}, {"country_code":"MT","country_name":"Malta"}, {"country_code":"MU","country_name":"Mauritius"}, {"country_code":"MV","country_name":"Maldives"}, {"country_code":"MW","country_name":"Malawi"}, {"country_code":"MX","country_name":"Mexico"}, {"country_code":"MY","country_name":"Malaysia"}, {"country_code":"MZ","country_name":"Mozambique"}, {"country_code":"NA","country_name":"Namibia"}, {"country_code":"NC","country_name":"New Caledonia"}, {"country_code":"NE","country_name":"Niger"}, {"country_code":"NF","country_name":"Norfolk Island"}, {"country_code":"NG","country_name":"Nigeria"}, {"country_code":"NI","country_name":"Nicaragua"}, {"country_code":"NL","country_name":"Netherlands"}, {"country_code":"NO","country_name":"Norway"}, {"country_code":"NP","country_name":"Nepal"}, {"country_code":"NR","country_name":"Nauru"}, {"country_code":"NU","country_name":"Niue"}, {"country_code":"NZ","country_name":"New Zealand"}, {"country_code":"OM","country_name":"Oman"}, {"country_code":"PA","country_name":"Panama"}, {"country_code":"PE","country_name":"Peru"}, {"country_code":"PF","country_name":"French Polynesia"}, {"country_code":"PG","country_name":"Papua New Guinea"}, {"country_code":"PH","country_name":"Philippines"}, {"country_code":"PK","country_name":"Pakistan"}, {"country_code":"PL","country_name":"Poland"}, {"country_code":"PM","country_name":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon"}, {"country_code":"PN","country_name":"Pitcairn Islands"}, {"country_code":"PR","country_name":"Puerto Rico"}, {"country_code":"PS","country_name":"Palestine"}, {"country_code":"PT","country_name":"Portugal"}, {"country_code":"PW","country_name":"Palau"}, {"country_code":"PY","country_name":"Paraguay"}, {"country_code":"QA","country_name":"Qatar"}, {"country_code":"RE","country_name":"R\u00e9union"}, {"country_code":"RO","country_name":"Romania"}, {"country_code":"RS","country_name":"Serbia"}, {"country_code":"RU","country_name":"Russia"}, {"country_code":"RW","country_name":"Rwanda"}, {"country_code":"SA","country_name":"Saudi Arabia"}, {"country_code":"SB","country_name":"Solomon Islands"}, {"country_code":"SC","country_name":"Seychelles"}, {"country_code":"SD","country_name":"Sudan"}, {"country_code":"SE","country_name":"Sweden"}, {"country_code":"SG","country_name":"Singapore"}, {"country_code":"SH","country_name":"Saint Helena"}, {"country_code":"SI","country_name":"Slovenia"}, {"country_code":"SJ","country_name":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen"}, {"country_code":"SK","country_name":"Slovakia"}, {"country_code":"SL","country_name":"Sierra Leone"}, {"country_code":"SM","country_name":"San Marino"}, {"country_code":"SN","country_name":"Senegal"}, {"country_code":"SO","country_name":"Somalia"}, {"country_code":"SR","country_name":"Suriname"}, {"country_code":"SS","country_name":"South Sudan"}, {"country_code":"ST","country_name":"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 and Pr\u00edncipe"}, {"country_code":"SV","country_name":"El Salvador"}, {"country_code":"SX","country_name":"Sint Maarten"}, {"country_code":"SY","country_name":"Syria"}, {"country_code":"SZ","country_name":"Swaziland"}, {"country_code":"TC","country_name":"Turks and Caicos Islands"}, {"country_code":"TD","country_name":"Chad"}, {"country_code":"TF","country_name":"French Southern Territories"}, {"country_code":"TG","country_name":"Togo"}, {"country_code":"TH","country_name":"Thailand"}, {"country_code":"TJ","country_name":"Tajikistan"}, {"country_code":"TK","country_name":"Tokelau"}, {"country_code":"TL","country_name":"East Timor"}, {"country_code":"TM","country_name":"Turkmenistan"}, {"country_code":"TN","country_name":"Tunisia"}, {"country_code":"TO","country_name":"Tonga"}, {"country_code":"TR","country_name":"Turkey"}, {"country_code":"TT","country_name":"Trinidad and Tobago"}, {"country_code":"TV","country_name":"Tuvalu"}, {"country_code":"TW","country_name":"Taiwan"}, {"country_code":"TZ","country_name":"Tanzania"}, {"country_code":"UA","country_name":"Ukraine"}, {"country_code":"UG","country_name":"Uganda"}, {"country_code":"UM","country_name":"U.S. Minor Outlying Islands"}, {"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States"}, {"country_code":"UY","country_name":"Uruguay"}, {"country_code":"UZ","country_name":"Uzbekistan"}, {"country_code":"VA","country_name":"Vatican City"}, {"country_code":"VC","country_name":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"}, {"country_code":"VE","country_name":"Venezuela"}, {"country_code":"VG","country_name":"British Virgin Islands"}, {"country_code":"VI","country_name":"U.S. Virgin Islands"}, {"country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam"}, {"country_code":"VU","country_name":"Vanuatu"}, {"country_code":"WF","country_name":"Wallis and Futuna"}, {"country_code":"WS","country_name":"Samoa"}, {"country_code":"XK","country_name":"Kosovo"}, {"country_code":"YE","country_name":"Yemen"}, {"country_code":"YT","country_name":"Mayotte"}, {"country_code":"ZA","country_name":"South Africa"}, {"country_code":"ZM","country_name":"Zambia"}, {"country_code":"ZW","country_name":"Zimbabwe"}]
```

If you are using RoboMongo, then if you want to insert multiple documents using RoboMongo in MongoDB collection in that case you need to remove the commas between two records, Use the following in case you are using RoboMongo.

```
{"country_code":"AD","country_name":"Andorra"} {"country_code":"AE","country_name":"United Arab Emirates"} {"country_code":"AF","country_name":"Afghanistan"} {"country_code":"AG","country_name":"Antigua and Barbuda"} {"country_code":"AI","country_name":"Anguilla"} {"country_code":"AL","country_name":"Albania"} {"country_code":"AM","country_name":"Armenia"} {"country_code":"AO","country_name":"Angola"} {"country_code":"AQ","country_name":"Antarctica"} {"country_code":"AR","country_name":"Argentina"} {"country_code":"AS","country_name":"American Samoa"} {"country_code":"AT","country_name":"Austria"} {"country_code":"AU","country_name":"Australia"} {"country_code":"AW","country_name":"Aruba"} {"country_code":"AX","country_name":"\u00c5land"} {"country_code":"AZ","country_name":"Azerbaijan"} {"country_code":"BA","country_name":"Bosnia and Herzegovina"} {"country_code":"BB","country_name":"Barbados"} {"country_code":"BD","country_name":"Bangladesh"} {"country_code":"BE","country_name":"Belgium"} {"country_code":"BF","country_name":"Burkina Faso"} {"country_code":"BG","country_name":"Bulgaria"} {"country_code":"BH","country_name":"Bahrain"} {"country_code":"BI","country_name":"Burundi"} {"country_code":"BJ","country_name":"Benin"} {"country_code":"BL","country_name":"Saint Barth\u00e9lemy"} {"country_code":"BM","country_name":"Bermuda"} {"country_code":"BN","country_name":"Brunei"} {"country_code":"BO","country_name":"Bolivia"} {"country_code":"BQ","country_name":"Bonaire"} {"country_code":"BR","country_name":"Brazil"} {"country_code":"BS","country_name":"Bahamas"} {"country_code":"BT","country_name":"Bhutan"} {"country_code":"BV","country_name":"Bouvet Island"} {"country_code":"BW","country_name":"Botswana"} {"country_code":"BY","country_name":"Belarus"} {"country_code":"BZ","country_name":"Belize"} {"country_code":"CA","country_name":"Canada"} {"country_code":"CC","country_name":"Cocos [Keeling] Islands"} {"country_code":"CD","country_name":"Democratic Republic of the Congo"} {"country_code":"CF","country_name":"Central African Republic"} {"country_code":"CG","country_name":"Republic of the Congo"} {"country_code":"CH","country_name":"Switzerland"} {"country_code":"CI","country_name":"Ivory Coast"} {"country_code":"CK","country_name":"Cook Islands"} {"country_code":"CL","country_name":"Chile"} {"country_code":"CM","country_name":"Cameroon"} {"country_code":"CN","country_name":"China"} {"country_code":"CO","country_name":"Colombia"} {"country_code":"CR","country_name":"Costa Rica"} {"country_code":"CU","country_name":"Cuba"} {"country_code":"CV","country_name":"Cape Verde"} {"country_code":"CW","country_name":"Curacao"} {"country_code":"CX","country_name":"Christmas Island"} {"country_code":"CY","country_name":"Cyprus"} {"country_code":"CZ","country_name":"Czech Republic"} {"country_code":"DE","country_name":"Germany"} {"country_code":"DJ","country_name":"Djibouti"} {"country_code":"DK","country_name":"Denmark"} {"country_code":"DM","country_name":"Dominica"} {"country_code":"DO","country_name":"Dominican Republic"} {"country_code":"DZ","country_name":"Algeria"} {"country_code":"EC","country_name":"Ecuador"} {"country_code":"EE","country_name":"Estonia"} {"country_code":"EG","country_name":"Egypt"} {"country_code":"EH","country_name":"Western Sahara"} {"country_code":"ER","country_name":"Eritrea"} {"country_code":"ES","country_name":"Spain"} {"country_code":"ET","country_name":"Ethiopia"} {"country_code":"FI","country_name":"Finland"} {"country_code":"FJ","country_name":"Fiji"} {"country_code":"FK","country_name":"Falkland Islands"} {"country_code":"FM","country_name":"Micronesia"} {"country_code":"FO","country_name":"Faroe Islands"} {"country_code":"FR","country_name":"France"} {"country_code":"GA","country_name":"Gabon"} {"country_code":"GB","country_name":"United Kingdom"} {"country_code":"GD","country_name":"Grenada"} {"country_code":"GE","country_name":"Georgia"} {"country_code":"GF","country_name":"French Guiana"} {"country_code":"GG","country_name":"Guernsey"} {"country_code":"GH","country_name":"Ghana"} {"country_code":"GI","country_name":"Gibraltar"} {"country_code":"GL","country_name":"Greenland"} {"country_code":"GM","country_name":"Gambia"} {"country_code":"GN","country_name":"Guinea"} {"country_code":"GP","country_name":"Guadeloupe"} {"country_code":"GQ","country_name":"Equatorial Guinea"} {"country_code":"GR","country_name":"Greece"} {"country_code":"GS","country_name":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"} {"country_code":"GT","country_name":"Guatemala"} {"country_code":"GU","country_name":"Guam"} {"country_code":"GW","country_name":"Guinea-Bissau"} {"country_code":"GY","country_name":"Guyana"} {"country_code":"HK","country_name":"Hong Kong"} {"country_code":"HM","country_name":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands"} {"country_code":"HN","country_name":"Honduras"} {"country_code":"HR","country_name":"Croatia"} {"country_code":"HT","country_name":"Haiti"} {"country_code":"HU","country_name":"Hungary"} {"country_code":"ID","country_name":"Indonesia"} {"country_code":"IE","country_name":"Ireland"} {"country_code":"IL","country_name":"Israel"} {"country_code":"IM","country_name":"Isle of Man"} {"country_code":"IN","country_name":"India"} {"country_code":"IO","country_name":"British Indian Ocean Territory"} {"country_code":"IQ","country_name":"Iraq"} {"country_code":"IR","country_name":"Iran"} {"country_code":"IS","country_name":"Iceland"} {"country_code":"IT","country_name":"Italy"} {"country_code":"JE","country_name":"Jersey"} {"country_code":"JM","country_name":"Jamaica"} {"country_code":"JO","country_name":"Jordan"} {"country_code":"JP","country_name":"Japan"} {"country_code":"KE","country_name":"Kenya"} {"country_code":"KG","country_name":"Kyrgyzstan"} {"country_code":"KH","country_name":"Cambodia"} {"country_code":"KI","country_name":"Kiribati"} {"country_code":"KM","country_name":"Comoros"} {"country_code":"KN","country_name":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"} {"country_code":"KP","country_name":"North Korea"} {"country_code":"KR","country_name":"South Korea"} {"country_code":"KW","country_name":"Kuwait"} {"country_code":"KY","country_name":"Cayman Islands"} {"country_code":"KZ","country_name":"Kazakhstan"} {"country_code":"LA","country_name":"Laos"} {"country_code":"LB","country_name":"Lebanon"} {"country_code":"LC","country_name":"Saint Lucia"} {"country_code":"LI","country_name":"Liechtenstein"} {"country_code":"LK","country_name":"Sri Lanka"} {"country_code":"LR","country_name":"Liberia"} {"country_code":"LS","country_name":"Lesotho"} {"country_code":"LT","country_name":"Lithuania"} {"country_code":"LU","country_name":"Luxembourg"} {"country_code":"LV","country_name":"Latvia"} {"country_code":"LY","country_name":"Libya"} {"country_code":"MA","country_name":"Morocco"} {"country_code":"MC","country_name":"Monaco"} {"country_code":"MD","country_name":"Moldova"} {"country_code":"ME","country_name":"Montenegro"} {"country_code":"MF","country_name":"Saint Martin"} {"country_code":"MG","country_name":"Madagascar"} {"country_code":"MH","country_name":"Marshall Islands"} {"country_code":"MK","country_name":"Macedonia"} {"country_code":"ML","country_name":"Mali"} {"country_code":"MM","country_name":"Myanmar [Burma]"} {"country_code":"MN","country_name":"Mongolia"} {"country_code":"MO","country_name":"Macao"} {"country_code":"MP","country_name":"Northern Mariana Islands"} {"country_code":"MQ","country_name":"Martinique"} {"country_code":"MR","country_name":"Mauritania"} {"country_code":"MS","country_name":"Montserrat"} {"country_code":"MT","country_name":"Malta"} {"country_code":"MU","country_name":"Mauritius"} {"country_code":"MV","country_name":"Maldives"} {"country_code":"MW","country_name":"Malawi"} {"country_code":"MX","country_name":"Mexico"} {"country_code":"MY","country_name":"Malaysia"} {"country_code":"MZ","country_name":"Mozambique"} {"country_code":"NA","country_name":"Namibia"} {"country_code":"NC","country_name":"New Caledonia"} {"country_code":"NE","country_name":"Niger"} {"country_code":"NF","country_name":"Norfolk Island"} {"country_code":"NG","country_name":"Nigeria"} {"country_code":"NI","country_name":"Nicaragua"} {"country_code":"NL","country_name":"Netherlands"} {"country_code":"NO","country_name":"Norway"} {"country_code":"NP","country_name":"Nepal"} {"country_code":"NR","country_name":"Nauru"} {"country_code":"NU","country_name":"Niue"} {"country_code":"NZ","country_name":"New Zealand"} {"country_code":"OM","country_name":"Oman"} {"country_code":"PA","country_name":"Panama"} {"country_code":"PE","country_name":"Peru"} {"country_code":"PF","country_name":"French Polynesia"} {"country_code":"PG","country_name":"Papua New Guinea"} {"country_code":"PH","country_name":"Philippines"} {"country_code":"PK","country_name":"Pakistan"} {"country_code":"PL","country_name":"Poland"} {"country_code":"PM","country_name":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon"} {"country_code":"PN","country_name":"Pitcairn Islands"} {"country_code":"PR","country_name":"Puerto Rico"} {"country_code":"PS","country_name":"Palestine"} {"country_code":"PT","country_name":"Portugal"} {"country_code":"PW","country_name":"Palau"} {"country_code":"PY","country_name":"Paraguay"} {"country_code":"QA","country_name":"Qatar"} {"country_code":"RE","country_name":"R\u00e9union"} {"country_code":"RO","country_name":"Romania"} {"country_code":"RS","country_name":"Serbia"} {"country_code":"RU","country_name":"Russia"} {"country_code":"RW","country_name":"Rwanda"} {"country_code":"SA","country_name":"Saudi Arabia"} {"country_code":"SB","country_name":"Solomon Islands"} {"country_code":"SC","country_name":"Seychelles"} {"country_code":"SD","country_name":"Sudan"} {"country_code":"SE","country_name":"Sweden"} {"country_code":"SG","country_name":"Singapore"} {"country_code":"SH","country_name":"Saint Helena"} {"country_code":"SI","country_name":"Slovenia"} {"country_code":"SJ","country_name":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen"} {"country_code":"SK","country_name":"Slovakia"} {"country_code":"SL","country_name":"Sierra Leone"} {"country_code":"SM","country_name":"San Marino"} {"country_code":"SN","country_name":"Senegal"} {"country_code":"SO","country_name":"Somalia"} {"country_code":"SR","country_name":"Suriname"} {"country_code":"SS","country_name":"South Sudan"} {"country_code":"ST","country_name":"S\u00e3o Tom\u00e9 and Pr\u00edncipe"} {"country_code":"SV","country_name":"El Salvador"} {"country_code":"SX","country_name":"Sint Maarten"} {"country_code":"SY","country_name":"Syria"} {"country_code":"SZ","country_name":"Swaziland"} {"country_code":"TC","country_name":"Turks and Caicos Islands"} {"country_code":"TD","country_name":"Chad"} {"country_code":"TF","country_name":"French Southern Territories"} {"country_code":"TG","country_name":"Togo"} {"country_code":"TH","country_name":"Thailand"} {"country_code":"TJ","country_name":"Tajikistan"} {"country_code":"TK","country_name":"Tokelau"} {"country_code":"TL","country_name":"East Timor"} {"country_code":"TM","country_name":"Turkmenistan"} {"country_code":"TN","country_name":"Tunisia"} {"country_code":"TO","country_name":"Tonga"} {"country_code":"TR","country_name":"Turkey"} {"country_code":"TT","country_name":"Trinidad and Tobago"} {"country_code":"TV","country_name":"Tuvalu"} {"country_code":"TW","country_name":"Taiwan"} {"country_code":"TZ","country_name":"Tanzania"} {"country_code":"UA","country_name":"Ukraine"} {"country_code":"UG","country_name":"Uganda"} {"country_code":"UM","country_name":"U.S. Minor Outlying Islands"} {"country_code":"US","country_name":"United States"} {"country_code":"UY","country_name":"Uruguay"} {"country_code":"UZ","country_name":"Uzbekistan"} {"country_code":"VA","country_name":"Vatican City"} {"country_code":"VC","country_name":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"} {"country_code":"VE","country_name":"Venezuela"} {"country_code":"VG","country_name":"British Virgin Islands"} {"country_code":"VI","country_name":"U.S. Virgin Islands"} {"country_code":"VN","country_name":"Vietnam"} {"country_code":"VU","country_name":"Vanuatu"} {"country_code":"WF","country_name":"Wallis and Futuna"} {"country_code":"WS","country_name":"Samoa"} {"country_code":"XK","country_name":"Kosovo"} {"country_code":"YE","country_name":"Yemen"} {"country_code":"YT","country_name":"Mayotte"} {"country_code":"ZA","country_name":"South Africa"} {"country_code":"ZM","country_name":"Zambia"} {"country_code":"ZW","country_name":"Zimbabwe"}
```

Comment: To import it through command line, you may use mongoimport --jsonArray --db your_db --collection countries countries.json

Comment: If you are using MongoDB Compass you can directly copy-paste it in Add Data->Import Document.

Answer (score 3):

Source data from http://GeoNames.org, this python script will let you insert geodata in mongodb and update in few seconds.
https://github.com/Albert-Gao/world-cities-mongodb

Here's another repo which provides data for about 138k cities,
https://github.com/nabilashraf/all-the-cities-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend googlePlaces API if you have access, it's pretty easy to use and you can then save the geolocation data in the DB.

this is better than having to keep a (very) long list of cities and countries of the world and having to join between them each time.

and nobody even started talking about Localization and languages...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Facebook API which provides an autocomplete service:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/

and then cache the data (which has JSON result) in Mongo if you really need to.

Comment: Thanks for the link.I won't prefer to cache in Mongo if the API is fast! Its a web application anyway & initially I could do with not having the overhead to maintain (and update!) large data!

Comment: I checked the facebook API, however its really for their ad platform.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you to checkout this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/turalus/openDB

This is for MySQL but, I can assure you that there are lots of ways to easily convert MySQL database into MongoDB supported format (JSON)